# Cursor Hover-Over Icon Information

Tags: icons, cursor

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Focal Fossa From 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Using 18.04, when I hovered the mouse cursor over a desktop icon or any icon,a description of, or the name of, what the icon represented would appear. I only get a preview window on the open browser icon on the tool bar now. I can't find anything in settings or Tweak. I'm sure it's simple but then so am I. I'm more than happy to supply any information needed.

Thank you in advance.
Greg

Comment: Excellent @vanadium I will do that tomorrow and report back on my results. Thank you. Greg.

Comment: My apologies @vanadium. I just can't find the package or the code to install either DING or Neo. I disabled all of my adblock and pop-up block. There's a list a files but none of them say "download me here" or "copy and paste this." I can learn to live without it. I'm sure you have more important issues to deal with but I will thank you for your time. Much appreciated. Greg

Answer (score 0):

Behavior has changed because desktop icons in 20.04 are not anymore provided by the file manager Files (nautilus), but through a Gnome Shell extension "Desktop Icons". So for now, this extension does not provide such feature.

In the mean time, improved forked versions of the extension have become available.

- [Desktop Icons NG (DING) by rastersoft](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2087/desktop-icons-ng-ding/) is an improved version that shows the full name of the icon when hovering over it. Ubuntu 20.10 and upwards moved to that extension.
- [Desktop Icons: Neo by mawi](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4337/desktop-icons-neo/) is a fork of the previous extension, said to further improve on that one

You may consider to disable the system installed extension and try one of these.

You can disable the default Desktop Icons extension in the Extensions tool. You may need to install that tool first with the command `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs` command. Alternatively, you can just use the terminal to disable the extension: `gnome-extensions disable desktop-icons@csoriano`.